# Date format in Sulu admin

Tags: symfony, sulu

The date format in Sulu admin seems to be dictated by the language selected (en = `M/d/YYYY`, fr = `dd/mm/yyyy`). The date format is applied to date pickers, and dates shown in the changelog.

But, in Australia (and the UK, and others) where the language is English, the date format needs to be `dd/mm/yyyy`. How do I change the date format used for my English speaking locale in the admin console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add en_au as a translation for the backend this should us the right date format, add the following sbippet to your config

```
sulu_core:
    locales:
        en: English
        en_au: Australia
   translations:
        - en
        - en_au
   fallback_locale: en
```

For direct support you should subscribe to our slack channel sulu.io#questions

Comment: Nice, i'll give that a try soon. I tried subscribing to the sulu slack yesterday, but I think I got invited to the wrong slack. Just received another email inviting me to the correct one.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, had to run `bin/console sulu:translate:export` after adding that config, and all good